# Count and show how many address have been written in .oft module

Tags: vba, outlook, bcc, oft

I have a .oft outlook model where I wish to dynamically show the number of address typed in the bcc field.

I searched a lot for a solution, with no success.

My idea is to put a label which value changes (incrementing or decrementing) when I add or remove an address.

Waiting for your answer,
Andrea

I tried to put a label, but Outlook asks me for a "script". I tried to insert the script "CurrentItem.Recipients.count" with no success

Comment: What code exactly have you tried so far? What exactly do you need to get - all bcc recipient from all email in the .oft file?